# Get New SP name using PowerShell script in Azure pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

If I rename file names and push to git branch, I want to get New SP name using PowerShell script in Azure pipeline. I have tried several option but I can't get new file name

Rename SPs and push to git

[image: 3 filese Rename and push to git]

PowerShell script to get Rename Scripts

[image: Powershell script to get Rename Scripts]

below script used to get New SP names.

```
$renamedFiles = git diff --find-renames --name-only --diff-filter=R $(firstcommit)~ 
$(lastcommit) -r $(Build.SourceVersion)

foreach ($file in $renamedFiles) {
    # Find rename information using git log.
    $renameInfo = git log --name-status --oneline -- $(firstcommit)~ $(lastcommit) -r | Select-String -Pattern "(R\d+)\s+$file" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
    if ($renameInfo -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "Rename Info: $renameInfo"
    }
}
```

but this code return empty names.